# C - Char array SEEMS to copy, but only within loop scope

Tags: c, arrays, regex, string, malloc

Right now, I'm attempting to familiarize myself with C by writing a function which, given a string, will replace all instances of a target substring with a new substring. However, I've run into a problem with a reallocation of a `char*` array. To my eyes, it seems as though I'm able to successfully reallocate the array `string` to a desired new size at the end of the main loop, then perform a `strcpy` to fill it with an updated string. However, it fails for the following scenario:

Original input for string: "use the restroom. Then I need"
Target to replace: "the" (case insensitive)
Desired replacement value: "th'"

At the end of the loop, the line `printf("result: %s\n ",string);` prints out the correct phrase "use th' restroom. Then I need". However, `string` seems to then reset itself: the call to `strcasestr` in the `while()` statement is successful, the line at the beginning of the loop `printf("string: %s \n",string);` prints the original input string, and the loop continues indefinitely.

Any ideas would be much appreciated (and I apologize in advance for my flailing debug `printf` statements). Thanks!

The code for the function is as follows:

```
int replaceSubstring(char *string, int strLen, char*oldSubstring,
    int oldSublen, char*newSubstring, int newSublen )
{
    printf("Starting replace\n");
    char* strLoc;

    while((strLoc = strcasestr(string, oldSubstring)) != NULL )
    {
        printf("string: %s \n",string);
        printf("%d",newSublen);
        char *newBuf = (char *) malloc((size_t)(strLen +
            (newSublen - oldSublen)));
        printf("got newbuf\n");
        int stringIndex = 0;
        int newBufIndex = 0;
        char c;
        while(true)
        {
            if(stringIndex > 500)
                break;
            if(&string[stringIndex] == strLoc)
            {
                int j;
                for(j=0; j < newSublen; j++)
                {

                    printf("new index: %d  %c --> %c\n",
                        j+newBufIndex, newBuf[newBufIndex+j], newSubstring[j]);
                    newBuf[newBufIndex+j] = newSubstring[j];
                }
                stringIndex += oldSublen;
                newBufIndex += newSublen;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("old index: %d  %c --> %c\n", stringIndex,
                    newBuf[newBufIndex], string[stringIndex]);
                newBuf[newBufIndex] = string[stringIndex];
                if(string[stringIndex] == '\0')
                    break;
                newBufIndex++;
                stringIndex++;
            }
        }
        int length = (size_t)(strLen + (newSublen - oldSublen));
        string = (char*)realloc(string,
            (size_t)(strLen + (newSublen - oldSublen)));
        strcpy(string, newBuf);
        printf("result: %s\n ",string);
        free(newBuf);
    }
    printf("end result: %s ",string);
}
```

Comment: Every single cast in your code is redundant and/or introduces errors; take them out

Comment: To improve your question, post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing calling this function with arguments that cause the problem, and show the output you get. For example perhaps you pass the wrong value for `strLen` argument, we can't tell from this snippet.

Comment: You don't allocate enough memory for the null terminator

Comment: `strcasestr` will ignore `strLen` anyway so if your goal is to work on counted strings, this function doesn't implement it. If your goal is to work on null-terminated strings then it introduces extra points of failure to require the caller to also pass the correct length; the function should call `strlen` as needed instead.

Comment: This function never does anything with `string` after `realloc`: you do `printf("end result: %s ",string);` but never return it to the caller or anything. I hope the calling code doesn't try to re-use the pointer you passed in as first argument... (that memory block has been freed by the realloc call).

Answer (score 1):

At first the task should be clarified regarding desired behavior and interface.

The topic "Char array..." is not clear.
You provide `strLen`, `oldSublen` `newSublen`, so it looks that you indeed want to work just with bulk memory buffers with given length.
However, you use `strcasestr`, `strcpy` and `string[stringIndex] == '\0'` and also mention `printf("result: %s\n ",string);`.
So I assume that you want to work with "*null terminated strings*" that can be passed by the caller as string literals: "abc".
It is not needed to pass all those lengths to the function.

It looks that you are trying to implement recursive string replacement. After each replacement you start from the beginning.
Let's consider more complicated sets of parameters, for example, replace `aba` by `ab` in `abaaba`.

Case 1: single pass through input stream

```
Each of both old substrings can be replaced: "abaaba" => "abab"

That is how the standard sed string replacement works:

> echo "abaaba" | sed 's/aba/ab/g'
abab
```

Case 2: recursive replacement taking into account possible overlapping

```
The first replacement: "abaaba" => "ababa"
The second replacement in already replaced result: "ababa" => "abba"
```

Note that this case is not safe, for example replace "loop" by "loop loop". It is an infinite loop.

Suppose we want to implement a function that takes null terminated strings and the replacement is done in one pass as with `sed`.

In general the replacement cannot be done in place of input string (in the same memory).
Note that `realloc` may allocate new memory block with new address, so you should return that address to the caller.

For implementation simplicity it is possible to calculate required space for result before memory allocation (Case 1 implementation). So reallocation is not needed:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* replaceSubstring(const char* string, const char* oldSubstring,
    const char* newSubstring)
{
    size_t strLen = strlen(string);
    size_t oldSublen = strlen(oldSubstring);
    size_t newSublen = strlen(newSubstring);

    const char* strLoc = string;
    size_t replacements = 0;

    /* count number of replacements */
    while ((strLoc = strcasestr(strLoc, oldSubstring)))
    {
        strLoc += oldSublen;
        ++replacements;
    }

    /* result size: initial size + replacement diff + sizeof('\0') */
    size_t result_size = strLen + (newSublen - oldSublen) * replacements + 1;

    char* result = malloc(result_size);

    if (!result)
        return NULL;

    char* resCurrent = result;
    const char* strCurrent = string;
    strLoc = string;

    while ((strLoc = strcasestr(strLoc, oldSubstring)))
    {
        memcpy(resCurrent, strCurrent, strLoc - strCurrent);
        resCurrent += strLoc - strCurrent;
        memcpy(resCurrent, newSubstring, newSublen);
        resCurrent += newSublen;
        strLoc += oldSublen;
        strCurrent = strLoc;
    }

    strcpy(resCurrent, strCurrent);

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char* res;

    res = replaceSubstring("use the restroom. Then I need", "the", "th");
    printf("%s\n", res);
    free(res);

    res = replaceSubstring("abaaba", "aba", "ab");
    printf("%s\n", res);
    free(res);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Corner case: Might get stuck with `while ((strLoc = strcasestr(strLoc, "")))`.  Otherwise, nice code.

Comment: @chux Thanks! Good observation! I just wanted to edit my post to add validation for `""` to return `NULL` since `sed` also returns with error in case of empty input pattern,  but when I thought about it closely I noted that it might be dependent on requirements. It might be responsibility of the caller to provide valid input (in the same way as all input pointers cannot be `NULL` and must point to valid strings). Of course the caller should be aware about 'undefined' behavior with empty input pattern and of course the caller should also check returned result for `NULL`.